# Can you square root both sides of an implicit equation to get the derivative?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, chain-rule, implicit-differentiation

Suppose you have $x^2=(4x^2y^3 + 1)^2$, can you square root both sides of the equation to make it simpler?

Comment: Well, you need to be careful with the signs.  If $A^2=B^2$ then $A=\pm B$...you don't have $A=B$ necessarily.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Where are the square roots?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$x= 4x^2y^3+ 1$  OR $-x= 4x^2y^3+ 1$.

Comment: Note that the solution need not adhere to one formula or the other for all $x,y$. It could be $x=1, y=0$ (left formula), but also $x=(1+\sqrt{17})/8, y=-1$ (right formula). If you want/have contuinuity, then a change can only happen when both sides are $0$. which is impossible here.